How to Include Chat History When Using Google Gemini's API
I'm trying to feed chat history to the Google Gemini API using a cURL request. I want to provide both the user's previous input and the model's previous response in the request. Here's the cURL command I'm using:
curl --location 'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent?key=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "contents": [
        {
            "role": "model",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "...model data"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "...user input"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "history": [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "Hello, I have 2 dogs in my house."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "role": "model",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "Great to meet you. What would you like to know?"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'

I'm not sure if I'm formatting the contents and history sections correctly.
I expected the model to understand the previous exchanges and continue the conversation accordingly.

What documentation mentions a history JSON key? Refer to multi-turn queries in this documentation: https://ai.google.dev/api/rest/v1beta/models/generateContent Also, see the example JSON in this document: https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/get-started/tutorial?lang=rest#multi-turn_conversations_chat

History is part of the same cotent you just have to put it in order
"contents": [
        {
            "role": "model",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "...model data"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "...user input"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

The final one is the current one that the model will answer based upon the history or all the other entries in contents.

I am going to see if I can help you with this in more detail.  I created a tool which can connect to any of the major AI's as well as local models.
I want them to be as realistic as possible when I interact with them.  Part of that is storing message in a database and then repopulating the history from the message history.  This also allows me to restart the program with code changes and then continue any existing conversations.
This is the schema for the conversation table, which has a string conversation ID, the user_id, and agent_id (agent=AI personality).
class Conversation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    conversation_id = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', name='fk_conversation_user_id'), nullable=False)
    agent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('agent.id', name='fk_conversation_agent_id'), nullable=False)
    agent = db.relationship('Agent')  
    messages = db.relationship('Message', backref='conversation', lazy=True)
    segments = db.relationship('ConversationSegment', backref='conversation', lazy=True)
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('idx_conversation_id', 'conversation_id'),
        Index('idx_conversation_user_agent', 'conversation_id', 'user_id', 'agent_id'),
    )

Messages have a conversationID:
class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    conversation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('conversation.id', name='fk_message_conversation_id'), nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    created_at = db.Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    updated_at = db.Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc), onupdate=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    fact_message_links = db.relationship('FactMessageLink', backref='message', lazy=True)
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('idx_message_timestamp', 'timestamp'),
        Index('idx_message_conversation_id', 'conversation_id'),
    )

I created a function to pull recent history from the messages table for any given conversation.  I needed to limit the number of messages and the maximum characters because when the context windows gets too big for some models is causes problems.
def get_conversation_history(conversation_pk, max_messages=50, max_characters=4096):
    # Query messages in reverse order (most recent first)
    messages = Message.query.filter_by(conversation_id=conversation_pk).order_by(Message.id.desc()).limit(max_messages).all()
    
    history = []
    total_chars = 0
    
    # Iterate through messages (which are already in reverse order)
    for message in messages:
        message_dict = {"role": message.role, "content": message.content}
        message_chars = len(message.content)
        
        # Check if adding this message would exceed the character limit
        if total_chars + message_chars > max_characters:
            break
        
        history.append(message_dict)
        total_chars += message_chars
    
    # Reverse the list to maintain the correct sequence based on Message.id
    return list(reversed(history))

Notice this method just is a list of role and content.
To convert it to a format that google can use I use this.
def transform_history_for_gemini(history):
    """Transform the conversation history into the format expected by Google Gemini API."""
    transformed_history = []
    for message in history:
        transformed_message = {
            "role": message["role"],
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": message["content"]
                }
            ]
        }
        transformed_history.append(transformed_message)
    return transformed_history

I keep an array of session objects for any chats.  In this case it's a session_google object.  This happens at startup if the current conversation is not already in the array.
if model_type == 'google':
    generation_config = {
        "temperature": 0.3,
        "top_p": 0.95,
        "top_k": 64,
        "max_output_tokens": 8192,
        "response_mime_type": "text/plain",
    }

    safety_settings = [
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"},
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"},
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"},
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"},
    ]

    model_object = genai.GenerativeModel(
        model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-exp-0801",                 #"gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
        safety_settings=safety_settings,
        generation_config=generation_config,
        system_instruction=system_instructions,
    )
    transformed_history = transform_history_for_gemini(history[-200:])
    print(transformed_history)
    session_google = model_object.start_chat(history=transformed_history)
    thread_openai = None
    model_groq = None

With the google API the history is added when the session is started not with each message like some of the other models.  This requires much less data transmissions especially since Google allows such a large context window.
Once the session has been created something like this can be used to handle sending messages to it and google maintains the conversation history for you except you also need to log it so you can rebuild it if you restart the program.
def process_message_google(session_google, memory_context, message):
    try:

        response = session_google.send_message(message)
        return handle_generated_text(response.text)
    except ResourceExhausted:
        error_message = "I apologize, but we've reached our daily limit for AI interactions. Please try again tomorrow or contact support if you need immediate assistance."
        return error_message
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing message with Google: {str(e)}")
        return "I'm sorry, but I'm experiencing technical difficulties. Please try again later."

Just to complete the explanation when you get a response or send it a message you should also be logging the data in the database:
def log_message_to_session(role, message_content, conversation):
    log_message(role, message_content)
    print(f"{role.capitalize()} message:", message_content)
    message = Message(role=role, content=message_content, conversation_id=conversation.id, timestamp=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    db.session.add(message)
    db.session.commit()

The libraries I am using for providing connectivity is flask, and SQLAlchemy is being used to interact with the database.
I hope this helps.

You have to include your chats to the "parts" list to make gemini to remember their chat history.
Example data:
{
    "contents": [
        {
            "parts": [
                {"text": "User: Hello"},
                {"text": "User: What was my previous message?"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Response:
{
  "candidates": [
    {
      "content": {
        "parts": [
          {
            "text": "Your previous message was: \"Hello\"\n"
          }
        ],
        "role": "model"
      },
      "finishReason": "STOP",
      "avgLogprobs": -0.08453522125879924
    }
  ],
  "usageMetadata": {
    "promptTokenCount": 11,
    "candidatesTokenCount": 9,
    "totalTokenCount": 20
  },
  "modelVersion": "gemini-1.5-flash"
}

for interactive mode you have to include into contents list to make gemini to remember their chat history.:
Example data:
{
        "contents": [
          {"role":"user",
           "parts":[{
             "text": "Hello"}]},
          {"role": "model",
           "parts":[{
             "text": "Great to meet you. What would you like to know?"}]},
          {"role":"user",
           "parts":[{
             "text": "What was my previous message"}]},
        ]
}

Response:
{
  "candidates": [
    {
      "content": {
        "parts": [
          {
            "text": "Your previous message was \"Hello\".\n"
          }
        ],
        "role": "model"
      },
      "finishReason": "STOP",
      "avgLogprobs": -0.30310314893722534
    }
  ],
  "usageMetadata": {
    "promptTokenCount": 21,
    "candidatesTokenCount": 8,
    "totalTokenCount": 29
  },
  "modelVersion": "gemini-1.5-flash"
}

